# Java ScrollPane on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jscrollpane

I wrote JPanel class where I load image. I'm trying to add a scrolls to this panel, but it didn't work. Can someone help me? Sorry for my bad language.

```
browser.setFileFilter(imgFilter); // ustawienie filtra
browser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
browser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
int result = browser.showOpenDialog(imagePanel);

if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // tworzenie obrazu

    imagePanel = new ImagePanel(browser.getSelectedFile());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imagePanel);
    scrollPane.setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    //add(imagePanel);
    add(scrollPane);
    //imagePanel.repaint();
    scrollPane.repaint();
}
```

And this is my imagePanel class:

```
    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    private File file;

    public ImagePanel(File file) {
        this.file = file;
        setSize(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH * 3/4);

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Wystąpił błąd podczas wczytywanie obrazu.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(img == null) return;

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens? any error ?did you able to see panel

Comment: u like to add Jpanel inside Jscrollpane?

Comment: @getlost Nothing happens. It just not working, image is not displaying.

Comment: @Krishna I have to do it on JPanel, because later i want to draw shapes on this img.

Comment: @user2316721 it's work fine for me.did you correctly add setsize ?? setSize(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH * 3/4);

try to resize form by draging corners

Comment: @user2316721 did you add scrollpane to jframe?this.add(scrollPane);
this.repaint();

Answer (score 2):

You should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` of the `ImagePanel` to give the panel a preferred size, which the scroll pane will use to determine whether or not to add scrolls. Generally, when doing custom painting, you always want to override the `getPreferredSize` of the drawing canvas panel, as the default is 0x0

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                // image is 256 x 256
                Image image = new ImageIcon("stackoverflow.png").getImage();
                JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        super.paintComponent(g);
                        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this),
                                             image.getHeight(this));
                    }
                };
                JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(imagePanel); 
                pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**With getPreferredSize**

[image]

**Without getPreferredSize**

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

A couple thing I see wrong with your current code.

1. Creating a new `ImagePanel` when you want to set the image. Instead just have a method like `setImage` in the `ImagePanel` class where you can just set the image and repaint.
2. Trying to `add(scrollPane);` at runtime without `revalidate()`.

See full example here.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Test {
    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        JButton button = createButton(panel, pane);

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton(ImagePanel panel, JScrollPane pane) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Change image");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    Image image = new ImageIcon(
                            chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()).getImage();
                    panel.setImage(image);
                    pane.revalidate();
                }
            }
        });
        return button;
    }

    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        Image image;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (image != null) {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return image == null ? new Dimension(150, 150) 
                                 : new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), 
                                                 image.getHeight(this));
        }

        public void setImage(Image img) {
            this.image = img;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I look at your solution and try fix my code but it still don't work.

Comment: Post a simple runnable example that demonstrate the problem, and uses your said fixes. And get rid of the `setSize`

Comment: Maybe has something t do with you creating new panel. Instead just add a method to the `ImagePanel` class `setImage(Image img)`, then call that method to set the image of the panel. No need to create a new panel. Remember to `repaint()` inside the method

Comment: Did you try and run my last code? It works for me. Try and figure out what you're doing wrong based on this code

Comment: Yes, i tried. I wrote again ImagePanel class with BufferedImage (for now without JScrollPane) but when i run program and try to maximilize frame picture extends over the whole frame.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you any further until you update your post with a runnable example. You're trying to make me debug code, that I can't see.